# Не хватает памяти на vps сервере debian

Tags: mysql, php, debian, vps, linux

Здравствуйте. В линуксах разбираюсь не особо, на уровне выполнения по мануалам.
Понадобилось поднять свой vps  сервер. нашел подходящего хостера, на серве debian c очень минимальной конфой: cpu 1 core 0.6 Ghz, 384 RAM. 
к серверу каждый 10 сек обращается примерно 30-50 юзеров, и частенько в php-лог'е вижу это:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

порой даже не могу законнектиться по ftp или через putty так как памяти не хватает.

**И самое главное, я не понимаю, почему памяти не хватает если при просмотре в 'top' показывает примерно что еще 200 метров свободно**: *Mem:    393216k total,   159172k used,   234044k free.*

скрипты и запросы к БД не особо нагруженные,скорость выполнения высокая.
погуглив, отрубил  innodb в mysql, и немного поменял значения ServerLimits.

вот скрин из "топа", может кто подскажет что нибудь? неужели 40 юзеров это такая прям сильная нагрузка?
[image: http://i6.imageban.ru/out/2014/07/07/22f3ad865de9029e8dbafc036596d107.png]

Comment: Решение только одно. Приобрести сервер помощнее

Comment: @deivan вопрос шашечек и поездки

Answer (score 2):

[[@snake22](/users/17010/snake22)](/users/17010/snake22), сообщения такого рода говорят, что память израсходована до максимума, указанного в php.ini. Соответствено можно эту планку поднять, можно провести оптимизации узких мест.

p.s. почему-то всегда казалось, что это предел памяти на один скрипт, обрабатывающий один запрос. Посмотрите, где именно PHP валится, может там дикий расход памяти.

upd

> tried to allocate 261900 bytes

Скрипт попытался отхватить 262 мб памяти просто так, потому что может. Ищите бутылочное горло.

Comment: но а как же этот момент: "порой даже не могу законнектиться по ftp или через putty так как памяти не хватает." ? то есть это не только к пхп относится, и ещё, в пхп.ини  лимит стоит memory_limit = 32M

иногда бывает зайду в putty пытаюсь запустить тот же top а мне пишет что-то типа (точно не помню) Cannot allocate memory и что то там про fork.
скрипты еще раз проверю но там настолько всё просто что утечки памяти быть не должно.
ps не 262Мб а 262 килобайта)

Comment: > Cannot allocate memory и что то там про fork.

Значит, при попытках что-то сделать сама система упирается в ограничание по ресурсам для своих внутренних процессов. У вас же есть все логи, смотрите `/var/log` - там много чего интересного. Но, с другой стороны, 384 RAM - IMHO, тут и смотреть незачем. Понятно, что катастрофически мало для дебиана.

Comment: @snake22, у Вас рутовые права на этом сервере есть?

--

Если нет, то кроме как поплакаться, все равно ничего не получится.

А если есть, то можно попробовать поискать (повспоминать) как решать проблему.

По крайней мере в свопе у Вас место есть. А память, которую top показывает как free -- напрямую с памятью, которая м.б. выделена процессу не соотносится (в принципе можно получить и больше, чем в free в данный момент).

Comment: @snake22

> в пхп.ини лимит стоит memory_limit = 32M

Это на один скрипт. При множественных подключениях расход памяти, понятное дело, мультиплексируется.

еще этих инишников обычно там много (по одному на каждый sapi), убедитесь, что работаете с правильным

Comment: @klopp но почему мало? если даже в панели управления сервером у хостера посмотреть, в графике RAM Usage память не превышает 170Mb. может я что-то не знаю в линуксе и стоит какое-то искусственное ограничение?

рут есть, логи все могу предоставить если надо

Comment: @snake22, для начала посмотрите в `bash` установленные ограничения на процесс

     ulimit -a

под пользователем, которым исполняется php (наверное из апача) и то же самое под рутом.

--

И, пожалуй, начинайте читать `man 5 proc`.

--

Сейчас футбол начинается. Надеюсь, завтра продолжим.

Comment: блин,  а как ulimit от имени апача запустить?
вот ulimit из под рута http://i.imgur.com/KUS6rNf.png

Comment: @snake22, `unlimited` предел памяти и процессов у рута -- уже хорошо.

--

Как посмотреть для пользователя, под которым работает апач?

Из рута посмотрите первое поле в выводе

      ps -ef | grep apa

Это будет имя пользователя.

Зайдите им, если понадобиться запустите `bash` и выполните `ulimit -a`.

Если зайти не удается, то попробуйте так:

      echo 'id; ulimit -a' | sudo -u `ps -ef | grep apa | awk '{ print $1 }' | head -1` bash

(впрочем, можно и сразу набрать эту строчку).

Comment: @avp извиняюсь за долгое отсутствие. запустил в консоли код с echo и выдало абсолютно тоже самое что и на скриншоте выше

Comment: @snaked3, что же, значит в самом деле в определенные моменты 490M (с учетом swap) не хватает.

Попробуйте [добавить](http://pingvinoff.net/2011/09/20/prostoj-sposob-uvelicheniya-razdela-podkachki-swap-bez-izmeneniya-tablicy-razdelov/) гиг-другой к swap и посмотрите, что будет. 

Учтите, при большом количестве процессов (запросов) может начать "ооочень сильно тормозить".

Answer (score 2):

> почему памяти не хватает если при просмотре в 'top' показывает примерно что еще 200 метров свободно

1. Кто сказал, что всё, что показывает top, позволительно захватывать вашим php-скриптам?
2. Момент захвата может и не совпадать с обновлением топа
3. 261900 в любом случае больше 234044

Comment: насколько я понял 261900 bytes а 234044k - килобайты. то есть выходит что  в данном случае 234044к больше чем 261900b

Answer (score 0):

VPS VPS'у рознь. Вы даже не сказали какой системой виртуализации пользуетесь (OpenVZ, KVM, Xen, Hyper-V, etc) Возможно ваш хостер "жульничает" и продает ресурсов несколько больше чем есть на самом деле ([overselling](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)). Так же не указана разрядность и версия ОС.

А так наверно стоит задуматься и приобрести машинку помощьнее.